# Literal types: 0x1ull vs 0x1llu

Tags: c, literals

My `gcc` compiler allows me to define an unsigned long long (i.e. 64-bit) literal as

```
#define A_LITERAL 0x1ull
```

--- or ---

```
#define A_LITERAL 0x1llu
```

Is there any difference between these two literal statements.  Is this common to other C compilers?

Comment: I'm voting this up since it taught me something. I already _knew_ both forms were valid but preferred `ULL` because it matched the `unsigned long long` type. However, it turns out the types are pretty fluid as well, allowing such "weirdness" as `long unsigned long`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287957/is-long-unsigned-as-valid-as-unsigned-long-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are allowed by the C standard (section 6.4.4.1).

The unsigned suffix `u` can be before or after the long `l` (or long long (`ll`)) suffix.

Comment: Marking this the answer as the question was in the context of C and this quotes the C standard.

Answer (score 6):

Both are the same: excerpt from n3337 draft of C++11 standard:

```
integer-suffix:
    unsigned-suffix long-suffix(opt)
    unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix(opt)
    long-suffix unsigned-suffix(opt)
    long-long-suffix unsigned-suffix(opt)

unsigned-suffix: one of
    u U

long-suffix: one of
    l L

long-long-suffix: one of
    ll LL
```

Comment: Cleaned up the optional indicators to make them stand out (were subscripted in the standard).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping my "paste" from the document would translate a little better than it did...

Comment: This isn't a C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

`ull` or `llu` force the compiler to treat a constant as an `unsigned` and `long long integer`.
The order of `ll` and `u` doesn't matter, nor their case. you may also write `LLU` or `ULL`.