# Is 'long unsigned' as valid as 'unsigned long' in C?

Tags: c, types

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287680/literal-types-0x1ull-vs-0x1llu) was recently asked about whether `ULL` or `LLU` was valid for specifying unsigned long long constants in C. I know they're both valid but I was thinking that `ULL` would be preferable since it matched the type `unsigned long long`.

However, I'm not so certain now. The `gcc` compiler allowed the following without complaint:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned int a = 1;
    int unsigned b = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is: are `int unsigned`, and other variations like `long long unsigned`, valid types according to the standard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ISO C11 standard states in `6.2.5 Types`:

> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int.
>
> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword *unsigned*) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.

However there's no mandate in that section as to the *order* in which the base type and `unsigned` modifier appears.

The controlling section is later in the standard, `6.7.2 Type specifiers`, paraphrased here:

> Type specifiers are `void`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `_Bool`, `_Complex`, `<struct-or-union-specifier>`, `<enum-specifier>`, and `<typedef-name>`.
>
> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there is more than one multiset per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

It then goes on to list all the multisets, such as `unsigned long, or unsigned long int`.

But the important phrase there is `the type specifiers may occur in any order`, meaning that  *all* of these are valid for that multiset:

```
unsigned long
long unsigned

unsigned long int
unsigned int long
long unsigned int
long int unsigned
int unsigned long
int long unsigned
```

Comment: For a more obscure example, note that `typedef int i;` and `int typedef i;` are equivalent.

Comment: @Mankarse, good point, 6.7 allows you to reorder storage class specifiers like `typedef` and type specifiers like `int`. I'd have to look twice if I ever saw `int typedef something` in the wild. I'd almost certainly track down and destroy anyone who used `i` as a type name :-)

Answer (score 0):

The order of the specifier dosen't matter.

```
unsigned long long  is the same as long long unsigned.
```

Both types are valid according to C standard(c99).

Comment: Is this quoted from somewhere in particular or did you just put it in a quote box?

Comment: It's not a quote box, it's a code box. But an attribution would be nice.

Comment: @haccks I don't see anything relevant on that page. Thanks for wasting more of my time. -1

Comment: @Potatoswatter; I have read this recently in the book i am following. I did't think that spending time to learn something is wasting of time.