# Right syntax to make contents of an array volatile?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, c99, volatile

I vaguely remember that the order of the `volatile` keyword has influence on wether you want the pointer to the array to be volatile or the contents itself. If I want the content to be volatile, do I need to write:

```
volatile short Array[];
```

or

```
short volatile Array[3];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either will do. It is the difference between

```
short volatile * ptr; /* pointer to volatile short */
```

and

```
short * volatile ptr; /* volatile pointer to short */
```

that matters.

`const` behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them will work fine. Order of specifiers doesn't matter.
Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287959/2455888) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: As you see in user694733 answer, the order may matter.

Comment: That's different thing.