# What is the meaning of "1ULL"in c programming language

Tags: c

```
for (x = 0; x < 1ULL<<(2*length); ++x){
```

this above line is a c program code which I downloaded. It has a part "1ULL". First I thought it was a mistake. but the code compiles and works well. can anyone please explain me what is that thing mean.

thank you....

Comment: Unsigned Long long  `ULL` suffix

Comment: Who is upvoting this???

Comment: @H2CO3: I am, for instance.  Just because the answer is easily googled, it doesn't meant that it's a bad question.

Comment: @H2CO3: Note that unlike in the linked "duplicate", the use of the suffix in the code here is significant and likely required (e.g. if `int` is 32 bits, the code would malfunction if the prefix were omitted and `length` could be 16 or larger).

Comment: Being new to C (more comfortable with Python), I did not recognize this "1ULL" expression as the combination of a numeric literal and type suffix. Visually, it looks more like "NULL" than it looks like "1". The specific form of this question was helpful to me; the marked duplicate did not show up when searching.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, as this version of the question is clearer and completer. Not a reason for an upvote, but it was also  the first google Result I got.

Answer (score 21):

Suffix `ULL` to an integer represents type specifier. It means

```
unsigned long long
```

You may also like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287767/2455888) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17287957/2455888) for more detail.

Answer (score 9):

Those letters modify the literal `1` and make it of type `unsigned long long`.

This is covered in C99 (ISO/IEC 9899) §6.4.4.1 Integer constants:

> ```
> integer-suffix:
> unsigned-suffix long-suffixopt
> unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix
> long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
> long-long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
> unsigned-suffix: one of
> u U
> long-suffix: one of
> l L
> long-long-suffix: one of
> ll LL
> ```

Comment: I already vote all of you, but I think answers are incomplete till you don't tell usability of it.

Comment: for example `sizeof(1) != sizeof(1ULL)`.

Comment: This is the only answer that properly addresses what the `1` is in `1ULL`. Upvoted.

Answer (score 7):

It's a way to signal to the compiler that the value must be considered as a `unsigned long long`.